# Calling an ArrayList of Strings to another class?

Tags: java, arraylist

Am I doing this correctly?

**test.java** (MAIN):

```
public class test {
    public static ArrayList<String> testArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
        test.add("blah1");
        test.add("blah2");
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> passTestArray() {
        return testArray;
    }

}
```

**secondClass.java**

```
public class secondClass {
    ArrayList<String> test = test.passTestArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(authors.get(i));
    }
}
```

Getting nothing as an output from the `secondClass` class. Not sure if I'm doing this correctly or not. :/

Comment: What you posted is not legal java code. You cannot have a for loop outside of a method. Not sure how you even got this code to compile.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @EugenHotaj, Do you know if I'm doing this correctly? Can you pass an array using a method in `test.java` to `secondClass.java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **secondClass.java**, you're creating a new ArrayList and then trying to call a method on it that doesn't exist. You'll need to do something more like the below to initialize your **test** class and call its methods.

```
public class SecondClass {
     private Test firstClass;
     private ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();

     SecondClass() {
         firstClass = new Test();
         test = firstClass.passTestArray(); 
     }

}
```

In the above, you'll be creating the **secondClass.java**, initializing your first class (**test.java**), and then calling its methods.